# Warning: Couldn't read data from file "logs.jsonl", this makes an empty POST

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cmd, docker-compose, grafana

I am following a tutorial [Using Grafana with Elasticsearch](https://www.metricfire.com/blog/using-grafana-with-elasticsearch-tutorial/#Setup), and created a docker-compose.yml file that contains grafana, elasticsearch, and dejavu. Grafana, Elasticsearch, and dejavu is currently running. I have downloaded a sampledata from [elastic](https://download.elastic.co/demos/kibana/gettingstarted/7.x/logs.jsonl.gz) and after I used 7zip to extract the .gz file **I attempt to upload it to my elasticsearch instance but it tells me**

**Warning: Couldn't read data from file "logs.jsonl", this makes an empty POST.**

**curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application**

**curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'localhost**

[image]

I don't seem to understand why it is saying it is empty if the file actually has a lot of logs in there.

this is just a preview of the contents inside of the file.

```
{"index":{"_index":"logstash-2015.05.18"}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T09:03:25.877Z","ip":"185.124.182.126","extension":"gif","response":"404","geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":36.518375,"lon":-86.05828083},"src":"PH","dest":"MM","srcdest":"PH:MM"},"@tags":["success","info"],"utc_time":"2015-05-18T09:03:25.877Z","referer":"http://twitter.com/error/william-shepherd","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:6.0a1) Gecko/20110421 Firefox/6.0a1","clientip":"185.124.182.126","bytes":804,"host":"motion-media.theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org","request":"/canhaz/gemini-7.gif","url":"https://motion-media.theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org/canhaz/gemini-7.gif","@message":"185.124.182.126 - - [2015-05-18T09:03:25.877Z] \"GET /canhaz/gemini-7.gif HTTP/1.1\" 404 804 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:6.0a1) Gecko/20110421 Firefox/6.0a1\"","spaces":"this   is   a   thing    with lots of     spaces       wwwwoooooo","xss":"<script>console.log(\"xss\")</script>","headings":["<h3>f-i-j-nl-ng</h5>","http://facebook.com/success/lodewijk-van-den-berg"],"links":["daniel-tani@facebook.com","http://nytimes.com/security/kathryn-sullivan","www.nytimes.com"],"relatedContent":[{"url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/cbs-crew-rat-fink-2368032","og:type":"article","og:title":"CBS Crew Rat Fink","og:description":"Near a couple of auto body shops (and a sharp new Space Invader mosaic that we&#039;ll post soon) near Temple and Westmoreland is a CBS wall with a nice Rat ...","og:url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/cbs-crew-rat-fink-2368032","article:published_time":"2008-01-14T08:05:26-08:00","article:modified_time":"2014-10-28T14:59:52-07:00","article:section":"News","article:tag":"Mark Mauer","og:image":"http://IMAGES1.laweekly.com/imager/cbs-crew-rat-fink/u/original/2430299/img_2049.jpg","og:image:height":"360","og:image:width":"480","og:site_name":"LA Weekly","twitter:title":"CBS Crew Rat Fink","twitter:description":"Near a couple of auto body shops (and a sharp new Space Invader mosaic that we&#039;ll post soon) near Temple and Westmoreland is a CBS wall with a nice Rat ...","twitter:card":"summary","twitter:image":"http://IMAGES1.laweekly.com/imager/cbs-crew-rat-fink/u/original/2430299/img_2049.jpg","twitter:site":"@laweekly"},{"url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/push-and-retna-in-koreatown-2368043","og:type":"article","og:title":"Push and Retna in Koreatown","og:description":"Yeah, I originally had this posted this morning as Push &amp; Ayer - Sorry. It looked like a Retna piece, but I saw the Ayer in there and thought that must ...","og:url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/push-and-retna-in-koreatown-2368043","article:published_time":"2008-01-29T07:28:32-08:00","article:modified_time":"2014-10-28T14:59:54-07:00","article:section":"News","article:tag":"Shelley Leopold","og:image":"http://IMAGES1.laweekly.com/imager/push-and-retna-in-koreatown/u/original/2430376/img_3671.jpg","og:image:height":"360","og:image:width":"480","og:site_name":"LA Weekly","twitter:title":"Push and Retna in Koreatown","twitter:description":"Yeah, I originally had this posted this morning as Push &amp; Ayer - Sorry. It looked like a Retna piece, but I saw the Ayer in there and thought that must ...","twitter:card":"summary","twitter:image":"http://IMAGES1.laweekly.com/imager/push-and-retna-in-koreatown/u/original/2430376/img_3671.jpg","twitter:site":"@laweekly"},{"url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/asylm-ruets-pdb-on-santa-monica-2368012","og:type":"article","og:title":"Asylm, Ruets, PDB on Santa Monica","og:description":"Not a new piece, but a well-hidden gem a little south of Santa Monica Blvd. in an alley off of Heliotrope or Edgemont. I&#039;ve been sitting on this for a w...","og:url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/asylm-ruets-pdb-on-santa-monica-2368012","article:published_time":"2008-04-22T15:11:15-07:00","article:modified_time":"2014-10-28T14:59:48-07:00","article:section":"News","article:tag":"Culture and Lifestyle","og:image":"http://images1.laweekly.com/imager/asylm-ruets-pdb-on-santa-monica/u/original/2430137/img_5027.jpg","og:image:height":"360","og:image:width":"480","og:site_name":"LA Weekly","twitter:title":"Asylm, Ruets, PDB on Santa Monica","twitter:description":"Not a new piece, but a well-hidden gem a little south of Santa Monica Blvd. in an alley off of Heliotrope or Edgemont. I&#039;ve been sitting on this for a w...","twitter:card":"summary","twitter:image":"http://images1.laweekly.com/imager/asylm-ruets-pdb-on-santa-monica/u/original/2430137/img_5027.jpg","twitter:site":"@laweekly"},{"url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/laurence-tribe-tangles-with-cbs-and-la-city-hall-2396867","og:type":"article","og:title":"Laurence Tribe Tangles with CBS and L.A. City Hall","og:description":"The United States Court of Appeals for the Ninth Circuit&rsquo;s Courtroom 3 - a miniature auditorium with comfortable, smoked salmon-colored seats - wa...","og:url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/laurence-tribe-tangles-with-cbs-and-la-city-hall-2396867","article:published_time":"2008-06-04T14:16:10-07:00","article:modified_time":"2014-11-26T14:43:59-08:00","article:section":"News","og:site_name":"LA Weekly","twitter:title":"Laurence Tribe Tangles with CBS and L.A. City Hall","twitter:description":"The United States Court of Appeals for the Ninth Circuit&rsquo;s Courtroom 3 - a miniature auditorium with comfortable, smoked salmon-colored seats - wa...","twitter:card":"summary","twitter:site":"@laweekly"}],"machine":{"os":"win xp","ram":3221225472},"@version":"1"}
{"index":{"_index":"logstash-2015.05.18"}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T12:28:25.013Z","ip":"79.1.14.87","extension":"gif","response":"200","geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":35.16531472,"lon":-107.9006142},"src":"GN","dest":"US","srcdest":"GN:US"},"@tags":["success","info"],"utc_time":"2015-05-18T12:28:25.013Z","referer":"http://www.slate.com/warning/b-alvin-drew","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24","clientip":"79.1.14.87","bytes":774,"host":"motion-media.theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org","request":"/canhaz/james-mcdivitt.gif","url":"https://motion-media.theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org/canhaz/james-mcdivitt.gif","@message":"79.1.14.87 - - [2015-05-18T12:28:25.013Z] \"GET /canhaz/james-mcdivitt.gif HTTP/1.1\" 200 774 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24\"","spaces":"this   is   a   thing    with lots of     spaces       wwwwoooooo","xss":"<script>console.log(\"xss\")</script>","headings":["<h3>charles-bolden</h5>","http://www.slate.com/success/barry-wilmore"],"links":["george-nelson@twitter.com","http://facebook.com/info/anatoly-solovyev","www.www.slate.com"],"relatedContent":[],"machine":{"os":"osx","ram":8589934592},"@version":"1"}
{"index":{"_index":"logstash-2015.05.18"}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T17:44:34.357Z","ip":"178.209.1.7","extension":"php","response":"200","geo":{"coordinates":{"lat":36.38025,"lon":-88.98547778},"src":"US","dest":"ET","srcdest":"US:ET"},"@tags":["success","security"],"utc_time":"2015-05-18T17:44:34.357Z","referer":"http://facebook.com/success/voskhod-1","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24","clientip":"178.209.1.7","bytes":7417,"host":"theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org","request":"/people/type:astronauts/name:john-phillips/profile","memory":296680,"phpmemory":296680,"url":"https://theacademyofperformingartsandscience.org/people/type:astronauts/name:john-phillips/profile","@message":"178.209.1.7 - - [2015-05-18T17:44:34.357Z] \"GET /people/type:astronauts/name:john-phillips/profile HTTP/1.1\" 200 7417 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24\"","spaces":"this   is   a   thing    with lots of     spaces       wwwwoooooo","xss":"<script>console.log(\"xss\")</script>","headings":["<h3>scott-parazynski</h5>","http://twitter.com/success/carl-walz"],"links":["lee-morin@www.slate.com","http://facebook.com/info/oleg-makarov","www.twitter.com"],"relatedContent":[{"url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/entropy-at-the-french-cottage-hollywood-2368119","og:type":"article","og:title":"Entropy at the French Cottage, Hollywood","og:description":"The French Cottage hotel stood a few feet away from Sunset and Highland, near a stretch of old hotels and motels which are vanishing as steadily and unn...","og:url":"http://www.laweekly.com/news/entropy-at-the-french-cottage-hollywood-2368119","article:published_time":"2007-08-09T08:48:14-07:00","article:modified_time":"2014-10-28T15:00:07-07:00","article:section":"News","og:image":"http://images1.laweekly.com/imager/entropy-at-the-french-cottage-hollywood/u/original/2430875/img_1444.jpg","og:image:height":"480","og:image:width":"640","og:site_name":"LA Weekly","twitter:title":"Entropy at the French Cottage, Hollywood","twitter:description":"The French Cottage hotel stood a few feet away from Sunset and Highland, near a stretch of old hotels and motels which are vanishing as steadily and unn...","twitter:card":"summary","twitter:image":"http://images1.laweekly.com/imager/entropy-at-the-french-cottage-hollywood/u/original/2430875/img_1444.jpg","twitter:site":"@laweekly"}],"machine":{"os":"win 8","ram":15032385536},"@version":"1"}
```

Comment: `logs.jsonl` is a directory, though, not a file. Also, please don't post screenshots, they are incredibly hard to read (and impossible for some)

Comment: @SiHa When I go to file explorer, it says its type is JSONL File.... & If you click on the screenshot it zooms in. But good to know

Comment: Your directory listing quite clearly shows that it's a directory. I imagine explorer is confused by the extension